# How to convert SQL table row into the first element of an array of objects in CosmosDB NoSQL using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

I have a table with 3 columns: ID, A, and B, and I need to transform the data into a CosmosDB document with a specific structure. The desired structure is as follows:

```json
{
  "id": ID (value from the ID column),
  "values": [{"key": A (value from the A column), "value": B (value from the B column)}]
}
```

To achieve this, I utilized the Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory.

I attempted to accomplish this using path expressions like ['values']['key'] and ['values']['value']  in mappings, but each time I ended up with an object instead of an array containing objects and this syntax is not supported ['values'][0]['key'].

Error message: JSON path "$['predictedIncidenceRates'][0]['key']" is not correct. Array accessor like [0] is not supported in the schema mapping sink.

I tried using the Mapping Data Flow expression builder to create a derived column with this expression:

```json
[
  {
    "id": key,
    "key": name,
    "value": sortOrder
  }
]
```

However, this resulted in an error.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to structure the CosmosDB document correctly with the given requirements? Additionally, if there's a better approach or any alternative solutions, I would appreciate any insights. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error message: JSON path "$['predictedIncidenceRates'][0]['key']" is not correct. Array accessor like [0] is not supported in the schema mapping sink.

The above error is solved when we remove the array accessor `[0]`, in the mapping activity as you can see below.
[image]

It got succeed when `[0]` is removed in the below output:
[image]

Sample data i stored in Azure SQL Database:

```js
Id  A   B
1   a1  b1
2   a2  b2
3   a3  b3
4   a4  b4
5   a5  b5
6   a6  b6
7   a7  b7
8   a8  b8
9   a9  b9
10  a10 b10
```

**Output in Azure Cosmos DB:**

As you can see in the below output the data which is in tabular format in Azure SQL DB has converted into hierarchical pattern

```js
{
    "id": "1",
    "values": {
        "key": "a1",
        "value": "b1"
    }
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "values": {
        "key": "a2",
        "value": "b2"
    }
},
.
.
.
.,
{
    "id": "10",
    "values": {
        "key": "a10",
        "value": "b10"
    }
}
```

To write array of objects in cosmos db, you can use dataflow in ADF. Below is the approach:

- Take source as Azure SQL and do aggregation by doing `Group By` with **Id** and aggregate with **Values**.
- Use **`collect(@(Key=A, Value=B))`** in `Expression` to store an array of object as shown in the below:

[image]

- `Sink` with Azure Cosmos DB by allowing it to Insert into the cosmos container then it stores in an array format as you can see in the below:

[image]

**Output in Azure Cosmos DB:**

As you can see in the below output the data which is in tabular format in Azure SQL DB has converted into hierarchical pattern by storing objects in an array format.

```js
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Values": [
        {
            "Key": "a1",
            "Value": "b1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Values": [
        {
            "Key": "a2",
            "Value": "b2"
        }
    ]
},
.
.
.
.
.,
{
    "Id": 10,
    "Values": [
        {
            "Key": "a10",
            "Value": "b10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Balaji, yes, but the main idea is that this object should be an item in the array. Essentially, the 'values' field should be an array with one object. In your case, it is just an object 'values': {'key': 'a10', 'value': 'b10'}, and it needs to be 'values': [{'key': 'a10', 'value': 'b10'}] or this object will not be deserialized correctly

Comment: When copying data from tabular source to hierarchical sink, array inside object is not supported. For more information please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping).

Comment: @AlehBelausau Answer has been edited according to the requirements please check.

Comment: Thanks a lot! collect(@(Key=A, Value=B)) worked gereat.